# RegOpenKeyEx returning Error 87 aka "INVALID_PARAMETER"

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, registry

I am implementing a recursive registry delete using RegOpenKeyEx, RegDeleteKey and RegEnumKey.

**Problem::** Though the code works perfectly fine for Vista x86/x64 and Win 7 x86/x64 but fails on XP for some keys in HKCR

**Problem Area::** HKCR\Installer\Products\SomeKey

**Error Code::** 87 (INVALID_PARAMETER)

**Weird Behaviour::** Deletes the key the moment I open the key using REGEDIT.

**Code::**

```
static BOOL RcrsvRegDel( HKEY hKey, LPTSTR lpszSub )
{
BOOL    bRet = TRUE ;
LONG    lRet ;
DWORD   dwSize = MAX_PATH ;
TCHAR   szName[MAX_PATH] ;
TCHAR   szFullKey[MAX_PATH * 2] ;
HKEY    hKeySub = NULL ;
HRESULT hr = NULL ;

do{
    lRet = RegOpenKeyEx( hKey, lpszSub, 0, KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | DELETE, &hKeySub ) ;
    printf("RegOpenKey:: %S :: lRet = %ld\n", lpszSub, lRet) ;
    if( lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        if( lRet == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND )
        {
            bRet = TRUE ;
            break ;
        }
        else
        {
            bRet = FALSE ;
            break ;
        }
    }

    while( ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != (lRet = RegEnumKeyEx(hKeySub, 0, szName, &dwSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) )
    {
        bRet = RcrsvRegDel( hKeySub, szName) ;
        if( bRet == FALSE )
            break ;
    }

    if( hKeySub != NULL )
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKeySub) ;
        hKeySub = NULL ;
    }

    lRet = RegDeleteKey( hKey, lpszSub ) ;
    printf("RegDelKey:: %S :: lRet = %ld\n", lpszSub, lRet) ;
    if( lRet == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        bRet = TRUE ;
        break ;
    }
}while(0) ;
return bRet ;
}
```

Any idea whats goin on?

**UPDATE::**

I have also tried the samDesired Parameter with following flags

-KEY_READ

-KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE

-KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS

-KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | DELETE

Neither of the above flag works :-(

Comment: What happens if you use the real path to the key, `HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer\...`?

Comment: @HarryJohnston- I haven't tried that...Lemme try and I will tell you the result. Thank you for the enlightment though :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston- Its still the same :-( ERROR 87

Comment: Double-check the output to see whether you've already deleted the key that you are unable to open (it might be enumerating twice).  List the contents of the branch you're deleting ahead of time and compare it to the output; perhaps some other program is adding and deleting keys at the same time you are.  Make sure you're compiling in Unicode.  Why are you using two backslashes as the path separator?  Why are you recursing to K7RT_RcrsvRegDel instead of to RcrsvRegDel, are they the same function?

Comment: Rather than appending the key names together to make a full path, it would be better to call `RcrsvRegDel(hKeySub, szName)` to do the recursion.

Comment: @HarryJohnston- Yes they are same functions. I have corrected it. My bad. I am checking it and I am sure of that no other process is writing the keys. Question:: Shouldnt' the error be ACCESS_DENIED instead of INVALID_PARAMETER in any of the case you have suggested. I must be doing something wrong here, but I am too bugged by this problem to even think straight right now :-(

Comment: You can't count on getting any particular error code.  I strongly recommend you try doing the recursion with the keys (`RcrsvRegDel(hKeySub, szName)`) to avoid doing any string processing.  Also get rid of KEY_WOW64_32KEY, it's redundant and could be causing trouble.  Is it always the same key that fails or are there several of them?  Can you tell us the actual key name?  Using a debugger, check that szName doesn't contain any odd Unicode characters (printf may be suppressing them).

Comment: I have tried that way and have also edited the question, but still the same problem and error code persists. The actual Key name is:: HKCR\Installer\Features\SomeGUID_Of_A_Product, HKCR\Installer\Products\SomeGUID & HKCR\Installer\Upgrade Codes\SomeGUID. I have tried deleting from the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer but the same ERROR code = 87

Comment: The key is actually named SomeGUID_Of_A_Product???  Have you tried first uninstalling any security software that may be present?  Have you checked that the actual contents of szName are as expected?  Have you tried more than one XP machine?

Comment: No, its an GUID. Yes, I have uninstalled the security products installed. Yes, I have checked the contents of "szName" and they are valid. Yes, I have tried on nearly 3 machines with same error codes. Even I have checked with the code given at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724235(v=vs.85).aspx and even this code is unable to delete the keys both from HKCR or HKLM. You can try it yourself for some installed keys present at your registry ( but not on some random self created test keys cuz it works perfectly for them ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this. Take the flag as input parameter and pass one flag for the RegOpenKeyEx and again a set of flags when calling the recursive function. I have tried your code and it is working perfectly now, though it is not sure as to what was it that was causing the problem.

```
static BOOL RcrsvRegDel( HKEY hKey, LPTSTR lpszSub, DWORD dwOpenFlags )
{
    BOOL    bRet = TRUE ;
    LONG    lRet ;
    DWORD   dwSize = MAX_PATH ;
    TCHAR   szName[MAX_PATH] ;
    HKEY    hKeySub = NULL ;
    HRESULT hr = NULL ;
    HANDLE  hProcess = NULL ;
    HANDLE  hToken = NULL ;

    do{
        bRet = SetPrivilege( SE_BACKUP_NAME, TRUE ) ;
        if( bRet == FALSE )
        {
            bRet = FALSE ;
            break ;
        }

        lRet = RegOpenKeyEx( hKey, lpszSub, 0, dwOpenFlags, &hKeySub ) ;
        if( lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS )
        {
            bRet = FALSE ;
            break ;
        }

        while( ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != (lRet = RegEnumKeyEx(hKeySub, 0, szName, &dwSize, NULL, 
            NULL, NULL, NULL)) )
            if( !RcrsvRegDel(hKeySub, szName, dwOpenFlags) ) 
            {
                bRet = FALSE ;
                break ;
            }

        lRet = RegDeleteKey( hKey, lpszSub ) ;
        printf("RegDelKey:: %S :: lRet = %ld\n", lpszSub, lRet) ;
        if( lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS )
        {
            bRet = FALSE ;
            break ;
        }

        if( hKeySub != NULL )
        {
            RegCloseKey(hKeySub) ;
            hKeySub = NULL ;
        }
    }while(0) ;
    return bRet ;
}

static BOOL SetPrivilege( LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege ) 
{
    LUID    luid ;
    BOOL    bRet = TRUE ;
    HANDLE  hToken = NULL ;
    HANDLE  hProcess = NULL ;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp ;

    do{
        hProcess = GetCurrentProcess() ;
        if( 0 == OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken) )
        {
            bRet = FALSE ;
            break ;
        }

        if( !LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, lpszPrivilege, &luid) )
        {
            bRet = FALSE ;
            break ;
        }

        tp.PrivilegeCount = 1 ;
        tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid ;

        if( bEnablePrivilege )
            tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED ;
        else
            tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0 ;

        if( !AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 
            (PDWORD)NULL) )
        {
            bRet = FALSE ;
            break ;
        }

        if( ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED == GetLastError() )
        {
            bRet = FALSE ;
            break ;
        }
    }while(0) ;
    if( hToken != NULL ) CloseHandle( hToken ) ;
    return bRet ;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks Abhineet. That worked perfectly. Thanks a lot man. But why have you used the SetPrivilege function?

Comment: You can read about that here:: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619(v=vs.85).aspx. I generally use that when working with the Registry Tree. Read it on msdn.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can not use RegDeleteKey with handle was opened with flag KEY_WOW64_32KEY.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx for info.
You have to use RegDeleteKeyEx with same keys.

Comment: I am sorry, I am updating the question. actually I have tried with other flags too but to no success :-(

Comment: I mean - you have to use RegDeleteKeyEx(hKey, lpszSub,  KEY_ALL_ACCESS |KEY_WOW64_32KEY)

Comment: Yeah but my application is 32-bit and I am trying to delete Keys from 32-bit registry tree, so it won't cause any problem. Apart from this, I am trying to access HKCR. Atleast it shouldn't throw error @ RegOpenkeyEx.

Comment: you are not listening to what Serge is telling you. A key handle that is opened with the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flag, like you are doing, cannot be passed to `RegDeleteKey()`, it has to be passed to `RegDeleteKeyEx()` instead. You cannot use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` on a non-WOW64 system.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `RegDeleteKey()` to delete a 32-bit key on a 64-bit system.  [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx) says as much:

> > The RegDeleteKey function cannot be used to access an alternate registry view.

You must use [`RegDeleteKeyEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847.aspx) instead.

Try something like this:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS)(HANDLE, PBOOL);
extern LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS fnIsWow64Process;

typedef LONG (WINAPI *LPFN_REGDELETEKEYEX)(HKEY, LPCTSTR, REGSAM, DWORD);
extern LPFN_REGDELETEKEYEX fnRegDeleteKeyEx;
```

.

```
BOOL WINAPI IsWow64Process_Impl(HANDLE hHandle, PBOOL Wow64Process);
{
    *Wow64Process = FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL WINAPI IsWow64Process_Stub(HANDLE hProcess, PBOOL Wow64Process)
{
    fnIsWow64Process = (LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "IsWow64Process");

    if ( NULL == fnIsWow64Process )
        fnIsWow64Process = &IsWow64Process_Impl;

    return fnIsWow64Process(hProcess, Wow64Process);
}

LONG WINAPI RegDeleteKeyEx_Impl(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpSubKey, REGSAM samDesired, DWORD dwReserved)
{
    return RegDeleteKey( hKey, lpSubKey );
}

LONG WINAPI RegDeleteKeyEx_Stub(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpSubKey, REGSAM samDesired, DWORD dwReserved)
{
    fnRegDeleteKeyEx = (LPFN_REGDELETEKEYEX) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("advapi32")),
        #ifdef UNICODE
        "RegDeleteKeyExW"
        #else
        "RegDeleteKeyExA"
        #endif
    );

    if ( NULL == fnRegDeleteKeyEx )
        fnRegDeleteKeyEx = &RegDeleteKeyEx_Impl;

    return fnRegDeleteKeyEx( hKey, lpSubKey, samDesired, dwReserved );
}

LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS fnIsWow64Process = &IsWow64Process_Stub;
LPFN_REGDELETEKEYEX fnRegDeleteKeyEx = &RegDeleteKeyEx_Stub;
```

.

```
BOOL IsWin64()
{
    #if defined(_WIN64)
    return FALSE;  // 64-bit programs run only on Win64
    #elif defined(_WIN32)
    // 32-bit programs run on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows so must sniff
    BOOL f64 = FALSE;
    return fnIsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &f64) && f64;
    #else
    return FALSE; // Win64 does not support Win16
    #endif
}
```

.

```
static BOOL RcrsvRegDel( HKEY hKey, LPTSTR lpszSub ) 
{ 
    BOOL    bRet = TRUE; 
    LONG    lRet; 
    DWORD   dwSize; 
    TCHAR   szName[MAX_PATH+1]; 
    HKEY    hKeySub = NULL; 

    REGSAM Wow64Flag = (IsWin64()) ? KEY_WOW64_32KEY : 0;

    lRet = RegOpenKeyEx( hKey, lpszSub, 0, KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | KEY_SET_VALUE | DELETE | Wow64Flag, &hKeySub ) ; 
    printf("RegOpenKey:: %S :: lRet = %ld\n", lpszSub, lRet) ; 

    if( lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
    {
        if ( lRet != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND )
            bRet = FALSE; 
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            dwSize = MAX_PATH;
            lRet = RegEnumKeyEx( hKeySub, 0, szName, &dwSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );

            if ( lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS )
            {
                if ( lRet != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS )
                    bRet = FALSE;

                break;
            }

            bRet = RcrsvRegDel( hKeySub, szName ); 
            if ( !bRet ) 
                break; 
        }
        while (1);

        RegCloseKey(hKeySub); 

        if ( bRet )
        {
            if ( Wow64Flag != 0 )
                lRet = fnRegDeleteKeyEx( hKey, lpszSub, Wow64Flag, 0 );
            else
                lRet = RegDeleteKey( hKey, lpszSub );
            printf("RegDelKey:: %S :: lRet = %ld\n", lpszSub, lRet) ; 

            if ( lRet != ERROR_SUCCESS )
                bRet = FALSE; 
        }
    }

    return bRet;
}
```

With that said, consider using [`RegDeleteTree()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379776.aspx) or [`SHDeleteKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773486.aspx) instead.  Let them do the recursion for you.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you have shown and the code above is really so smooth but still my problem is OPENING the key. Let me make myself more clear if the question is not so obvious::

Comment: 1. Why RegOpenKeyEx is failing with ERROR 87 even with a simple flag of KEY_READ or KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS.
2. As the documentation @ MSDN says, "By default, a 32-bit application running on WOW64 accesses the 32-bit registry view and a 64-bit application accesses the 64-bit registry view.", So, I am not trying to access any alternate registry as my application is 32-bit, I have mentioned the flag to be super-precautious. 
3. The code works fine for x86 and x64 with VISTA or WIN 7, so i dont think using RegDeleteKey would be causing any problem here.

Comment: Without seeing your code that is calling `RcrsvRegDel()`, it is hard to diagnose why `RegOpenKeyEx()` is failing.  Chances are that either `hKey` or `lpszSub` really do contain invalid values.  Make sure you are also not trying to access a key that is virtualized under WOW64, that might also be playing a factor.

Comment: @user1696837: you really should have mentioned when you first asked the question that the error code was coming from the RegOpenKeyEx call rather than the RegDeleteKey call.  We've been wasting our time trying to solve a problem you didn't have instead of the one you did.

Comment: What is your `printf()` statement outputting when `RegOpenKeyEx()` fails?  Did you validate that `lpszSub` is a valid string path that is relative to the `hKey` key?

Comment: @HarryJohnston- I have mentioned it in my title :-) And you havent' been wasting your time, I still got so much to try from your ideas. Best one was:: Delete the keys from "HKLM\Classes\Installer" :-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau- Output:: "RegOpenKey:: Installer\Products\SomeKey :: lRet = 87" Yes the lpszSub is a valid path.

Comment: Definitely use `HKLM\Software\Classes` and `HKCU\Software\Classes`. `HKCR` should only be used for reading, not for modifying.